# How can I change type of the input box using values from select box?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, contact-form

```js
 
$(function() { 
    var index = 1; 
    $("#addcon").on("click", function() {  
        num = index + 1;
        $("table.contact").append(`
            <tr>
                <td class='label'><label class='required'>Contact ${num}</label></td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><select name=contact[${index}][type] class='contact' required>
                    <option style='display: none;' value='' selected>Select Type</option>
                    <option>Mobile</option>
                    <option>Landline</option>
                    <option>Email</option>
                    <option>Other</option>
                </select></td>
                <td><input type='text' name=contact[${index}][way] maxlength='300' class='way' required></td>
            </tr>
        `);
        index++;
    }); 
    
    $("#remcon").on("click", function() {  
        if(index - 1 >= 1) {
            $("table.contact tr").last().remove();
            index--;
        }
        else {  
            alert("One is must!");
        }
    });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="contact">
    <tr class="legend">
        <td colspan="6">CONTACT DETAILS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label"><label class="required">Contact 1</label></td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><select name="contact[0][type]" required class="contact">
            <option style="display: none;" value="" selected>Select Type</option>
            <option>Mobile</option>
            <option>Landline</option>
            <option>Email</option>
            <option>Other</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="contact[0][way]" required class="way"></td>
        <td style="text-align:left;"><a id="addcon" class="click">+</a></td>
        <td><a id="remcon" class="click">-</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Above is my table in a contact detail form. User can input any number of contacts by clicking on the "+" link and remove by clicking the "-" link. But in order to validate the data, I need to change the 'type' of the input field as per the selection in the respective select box (combo box). Is there any way to do that using JQuery?

*Example:* if I select email in select box, the type of input field respective to this select box should change to type email.

Comment: You can add an `onChange` event to your `<select>` elements and generate IDs for your inputs, that way, when a user selects something, the event callback is executed, which will save the value and update the corresponding `<input>` accordingly.

Comment: onChange on <select> is ok to do.

Comment: but how can i change attributes of input boxes?

Comment: For something like `<input id="x" />`, it's `$('#x').attr('type', 'text');`.

Comment: so how can i add more input boxes? giving numbers as id is not valid. so how...?

Comment: i have to add more fields and change the type of each field with respective `<select>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your requirement, the idea is, when creating a new row, you need to attach a [*change*](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event listener to your `<select>` element, and when the user selects an option, the event callback will trigger an attribute change on the `<input>` element using jQuery's [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method.

You will also need to create some sort of a mapping between the option values and actual HTML input types that you can find [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp).

I've taken the liberty to refactor your code a little bit to create a few methods that help with code repetition. I've also move the **+** and **-** link buttons to the header of the table because there is no reason for them to be attached to the first contact.

Below is a working snippet.

```js
// mapping object from <select> values to input types
const selectTypesMapping = {
    Mobile: 'number',
    Landline: 'password',
    Email: 'email'
};
// gets a label cell
const getLabelCell = (index) => (`
    <td class="label">
        <label class="required">Contact ${index}</label>
    </td>
`);
// gets a colon cell
const getColonCell = () => (`<td>:</td>`);
// gets a select cell with a configured ID
const getSelectCell = (index) => (`
    <td>
        <select id="select-${index}" name="contact[index][type]"
                class="contact" required>
            <option style="display: none;" value="" selected>Select Type</option>
            <option>Mobile</option>
            <option>Landline</option>
            <option>Email</option>
            <option>Other</option>
        </select>
    </td>
`);
// gets an input cell with a configured ID
const getInputCell = (index) => (`
    <td>
        <input id="input-${index}" type="text" name="contact[index][way]" 
               maxlength="300" class="way" required />
    </td>
`);
// appends a row to a jQuery table and adds the change event to the select
const appendRow = (jQueryTable, index) => {
    jQueryTable.append(`
        <tr>
            ${getLabelCell(index + 1)}
            ${getColonCell()}
            ${getSelectCell(index)}
            ${getInputCell(index)}
        </tr>
    `);
    $(`#select-${index}`).change((event) => {
        $(`#input-${index}`).attr('type', selectTypesMapping[event.target.value]);
    });
};

$(function() {
    // manually append 1st row
    appendRow($('table.contact'), 0);
    let index = 1;
    $('#addcon').on('click', function() {
        // append on click and increment index
        appendRow($('table.contact'), index++);
    });
    $('#remcon').on('click', function() {
        if (index > 1) {
            $('table.contact tr').last().remove();
            index--;
        }
        else {
            alert('At least one contact is required!');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.click {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="contact">
    <tr class="legend">
        <td colspan="4">CONTACT DETAILS</td>
        <td style="text-align:left;"><a id="addcon" class="click">+</a></td>
        <td><a id="remcon" title="Add" class="click">-</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Ghassen Louhaichi... Great... thanks for helping me to code... and study programming... Gave me the exact solution...